# Microsoft.Net intermediate code in linux or Mac

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, c#-3.0

I am working in c#.Net. Is there any way to make .Net application plateform independent? So that I can run it to any OS. Kindly give me some guideline. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should [take a look at Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/):

> An open source, cross-platform,
>   implementation of C# and the CLR that
>   is binary compatible with
>   Microsoft.NET

Comment: Is there any option to access the byte code of the application? 2nd can we directly execte our byte code in any plateform?

Comment: @Arman: I'm not sure what you mean. In theory you can execute exactly the same bytecode on different platforms but some restrictions apply. For example, any P/Invoke stuff will necessarily be platform-specific.

Answer (score 2):

You could also take a look at [dotgnu portable.net](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/pnet.html), the little known alternative to Mono.